# Laravel using one place to define colors for controllers and views

Tags: php, css, laravel

Hello im currently trying to build a laravel page.

i am building up data and colors for my js/jquery charts in the controller.
but im also using the same colors for my general app layout in the css file.

now where would i want to set colors to be able to change a certain color for all charts in my controllers and the layout in my css file?

Let's say i have a certain color for "bad" #ff0000, i want to change it to a diffrent tone of red like #ce2500 and i don't want to change every occurence.

you get the idea i guess?

or am i thinking / doing something completely wrong here?

**EDIT what i have done so far:**

in the CSS file i defined my colors for my app to stay in a certain style.
custom.css.php:

```
--color_bad: #ff0000;
--color_good: #00a6eb;
--color_text: #000000;
--color_bg1: #e6e6e6;
--color_bg2: #b3b3b3;
--color_border: #4d4d4d;
--color_caption: #ffffff;
```

I also did this in the config for the controllers:

```
    // COLORS

'color_bad' => '#ff0000', 
'color_good' => '#00a6eb', 
'color_text' => '#000000', 
'color_bg1' => '#e6e6e6',
'color_bg2' => '#b3b3b3', 
'color_border' => '#4d4d4d',    
'color_caption' => '#ffffff',
```

im using the css variables through the css files and `config('colors.color_bad')` for the controllers

so i brought it down to 2 points in the app where colors are defined
and i wanted to break it furhter down to only one place

Comment: That what `SASS` and `LESS` [were invented for](https://davidwalsh.name/sass-color-variables-dont-suck). However you could add it to the config if you really want to do it without a "new" language / compiler. For the `js` part: add classes not styling (seperation of concerns)

Comment: hmm well im using a chartbuilder i pass all variables and only call the render function in the view dunno if that is right =/ at least taht way i don't know how i could pass colors without defining them before the view is called =/

Answer (score 2):

For most constants used globally across the application, storing them in config files is sufficient. It is also pretty simple

Create a new file in the app/config directory. Let's call it constants.php

In there you have to return an array of config values.

```
return [
    'langs' => [
        'es' => 'www.domain.es',
        'en' => 'www.domain.us'
        // etc
    ]
];
```

And you can access them as follows

```
Config::get('constants.langs');
```

// or if you want a specific one
Config::get('constants.langs.en');
And you can set them as well

```
Config::set('foo.bar', 'test');
```

Comment: that was my first thought, i stored them there for every controller, but i can't access the config in the css file can i? Or am i supposed to pass the colors to every view even thought there is no condition to it?

Comment: @user3665396 You also not acces the controler in css you have to give the incline css or in the view of controller

Comment: I think this is a bad location to store css constants. But yes it will work.